Line Integral round the unit circle
I need to compute line integral $$\int_C \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 + 4y^2}$$ round the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$.
My approach is outlined below:
Taking $x = \cos\theta, y = \sin\theta$
$$
\begin{align}
I & = \int_C \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2 + 4y^2}\\
& = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\cos\theta d(\sin\theta)-\sin\theta d(\cos\theta)}{{\cos^2\theta} + 4{\sin^2\theta}}\\
& = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{d \theta}{{\cos^2\theta} + 4{\sin^2\theta}}\\
& = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\sec^2\theta d \theta}{1 + 4{\tan^2\theta}}
\end{align}$$
Is this step in the right direction? The given answer for this question is $\pi$, but I'm getting $0$. Not sure where am I making mistake.

Note that your integrand is not defined on the whole interval $[0,2\pi]$ after you divide $\cos^2\theta$ (Not a big deal). Moreover, when you make the substitution $u=\tan\theta$, it results both bounds become the same (since your transformation is not injective in the interval.)

@AngaeMT yes, using substitution $u=tan\theta$ is making both bounds same. Why should be the ideal approach here?

Easier to replace $\cos^2 \to 1-\sin^2$, both  integrals yield $\pi$. Standard  substitution for the full circle $$ \phi \to 2 \tan^{-1} t , \sin \phi\to \frac{2t }{1+t^2}$$

@AjitSharma If you want to keep using the substitution, you may need to decompose the integral into 4 intervals $[0,\pi/2),(\pi/2,\pi),\cdots,(3\pi/2,2\pi)$ bc you want the integrand to be well-defined within the interval. Then you sum back up all will get the desired answer.

Whoops, I tried linking this to the divergence theorem and using that to solve this, but I also ended up getting $0$.

Note that this field is locally conservative. Indeed, writing
$$
\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+4y^2}=F_xdx+Fydy,
$$
you get:
$$\frac{\partial F_x}{ \partial y}=-\frac{1}{x^2+4y^2}+\frac{8y^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}=\frac{4y^2-x^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial F_y}{ \partial x}=\frac{1}{x^2+4y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}=\frac{4y^2-x^2}{(x^2+4y^2)^2}.
$$
so
$$\frac{\partial F_x}{ \partial y}=\frac{\partial F_y}{ \partial x}$$.
That is, $F$ is a conservative field. Thus, you can integrate on any path homotopic to the circle and get the same result. I suggest the ellipsoid $x^2+4y^2=1$.

Yes, I found out that the field is conservative. If thats the case, I should be able to find out the field potential and compute the line integral as difference of the potentials, right? If that's the case , integral should be taken as twice of $\phi (-1,0) -\phi(1,0) $. Am I correct here?

If $\vec{F}$ is conservative, and $C$ is the unit circle, then surely it would evaluate to $0$ because $C$ is closed?

The answer to both comments is no, and for the same reason. While an integral along a closed curve of a conservative field is zero, this is not the case here. The field is locally conservative, which is different from conservative. They are the same only when the domain of the field is simply connected, or more precisely, when the path of integration encloses an area on which the field is defined. In the case of this field, it is not defined in the origin, which is included in the area bounded by the circle. Thus, locally conservative and conservative are not the same.

In fact, this function does not have a potential in the entire space, but only locally. However, in the same manner as how locally conservative and conservative are the same in an area enclosed by a loop on which the field is defined, it is always true that the path integral of a locally conservative field is the same on paths that can be deformed from one to another within the domain of definition. In this case it means, that passing the curve through the origin is not allowed, but any other continuous deformation is okay. Specifically, changing the curve from a circle to an ellipse.

Moreover, a proof that this field has no potential relies on the fact that the integral in question is nonzero. Evaluating it on the ellipse is easier, resulting in, I suppose, $2\pi$.
